# generate a daily test execution report in HP ALM

Tags: testing, alm, hp-quality-center

I want to generate a daily test execution report for one of my regression set (which is in 1 folder and that 1 regression has multiple sub folders inside it , which contains test sets).
I tried running below query but not getting any output from that

```
SELECT
TESTCYCL.TC_USER_03 as Defect_ID,
TESTCYCL.TC_STATUS as Status,
--TESTCYCL.TC_ACTUAL_TESTER as Tester,
TESTCYCL.TC_EXEC_DATE as Exec_Date,
TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID as Test_ID,
TESTCYCL.TC_USER_01 as Build_Number,
TEST.TS_NAME As 'plan name'
FROM
TESTCYCL,
test
WHERE TESTCYCL.TC_EXEC_DATE = '18/08/2022'
AND TESTCYCL.TC_ACTUAL_TESTER = 'anurag.kulshreshtha'
AND TEST.TS_TEST_ID = TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID
```

tried to check on google as well but no luck...can someone please help?

Comment: do you mean ...FROM TESTCYCL as TEST WHERE...

Comment: Yes, right but this is not working somehow

Comment: how about ...from TESTCYCL left join TEST on TEST.TS_TEST_ID = TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID  WHERE condition1 AND condition2